# Which bootloader is used in VxWorks?

Tags: bootloader, vxworks

Does VxWorks come with a built in Boot loader?
if not then which boot loader should be used to boot it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VxWorks does have a bootloader aka bootrom which comes with each BSP and can be customized if necessary, see the vxworks kernel programmer's guide for more information.